# Fully qualified reference to Java method signature

Tags: java

What is the *proper* way to write a fully qualified reference to a method name in Java?

1. `Message[] com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder#addMessages(Message[])`
2. `Message[] com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.addMessages(Message[])`
3. Some other way

Comment: with what purpose? JNDI?

Comment: Also, but not just. Isn't it there an official way to write references? I can't certainly use "any" character "anywhere", like com$sun%mail^... Somewhere I find "#" used to separate Class and Method names, somewhere else I find ".", it's confusing. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Allow me to add that my use of JNDI is through Commons Configuration, using a "JNDIConfiguration" object where keys should be FQ method names. This is not the only case, as I said above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the signature of the method is `Message[] addMessages(Message[] msgs)`...

...and the class name is `IMAPFolder`...

...and it's in the package `com.sun.map.imap`...

...then the fully qualified method name would be `com.sun.map.imap.IMAPFolder.addMessages(Message[] msgs)`.

Visible class/instance variables share the same pattern, although for the sake of OO design, this is typically discouraged.

Normally, one only concerns themselves with the fully qualified object name, not the method/[instance|class] variable name.

Comment: Could you please add to your answer the source of this recommendation that makes it more or less "official"?

Comment: In terms of the FQCN, you can find the wiki link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name).  In terms of the OO recommendation, this is what I've seen and encountered; encapsulation is broken if you're using public variable names instead of accessors (and don't get me started on static variables).

Comment: Actually, the JavaDoc uses # instead of .

Comment: @Robottinosino:  You sure you're not getting it mixed up with anchor links generated by Javadoc?  I've not seen that notation used explicitly in Java before, maybe Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official proper syntax

- for Java7 at
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2
- for Java8 at
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.2
- for Java6 at
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html#14757