# java package does not exist and bad source file

Tags: java, package

So I made a folder called util and placed four classes along with program named unit10Assignment in it. I created a package util and typed " package util; " at the top of each one of the classes code like this:

```
package util;

public class Employee
```

Then i wrote:

```
import util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class unit10Assignment
```

On top of the program. However when I compile it, it tells me. Anyone know why? I tried playing around with it and it disappeared when I typed in import java.util*; instead but I'm not sure that what my teacher wanted as her example did not have the java in front.

It also says " bad source file" "package does not contain class Employee " However, everything compiled and ran perfectly before I typed in the package statement and I have not made any change to the code since then. If I removed the package statement from the employee class tho, the same message would appear but it would say another class does not exist.

Thanks for any help
Note: whether or not i put java.util or just util, this problem with the bad source still appears.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make the assumption that you have your project set up like this:

```
util/
    Employee.java
    unit10Assignment.java
bin/
```

(If it isn't, that's fine - so long as they're in *some* folder.  `bin/` should exist, though.)

The way that packages work is that they're folders on the hard drive - the package you want to import requires that the folder and class you wish to import both exist *in that specific folder*.  This is why packages are handy - you can have two classes named `Employee` and have them live in completely different locations.<sup>*</sup>

Here's how you compile these into a package-like structure without the use of an IDE.  Substitute $HOME for the full path of your Java class folder.

```
javac -sourcepath $HOME/util -d $HOME/bin *.java
```

And here's how you run your main class:

```
java -cp $HOME/bin util.$MAIN_CLASS
```

A breakdown of what these flags mean:

- `-sourcepath` instructs javac to look in this specific directory for your source files.
- `-d` specifies an output directory for your .class files.
- `-cp` instructs java to add this folder to its classpath.

<sup>*:  Really, really large projects can often use the same name as other classes; if you wanted to use a specific one, you'd have to use the [fully-qualified class name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778101/1079354) for it.</sup>

Comment: It's just a folder, much like `util/` is.  Usually that's where binaries live in a project (hence **bin**).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

- the filename matches the class name (e.g. `Employee.java` for class `Employee`)
- the files are inside the corresponding folder according to their package (i.e. `util`)

Are you using any IDE? If not, using one realy helps a lot with this kind of things.