# code from a book is not compiling[headintojava]

Tags: java

I could not get my code to compile, I even copied the code from the github here it is

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMusicPlayer1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            for(int i = 5; i < 61; i += 4) {
                track.add(makeEvent(144,1,i,100,i));
                track.add(makeEvent(128,1,i,100,i + 2));
            }

            sequencer.setSequence(seq);
            sequencer.setTempoInBPM(220);
            sequencer.start();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {
        MidiEvent event = null;
        try {
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
            event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
        return event;
    }
}
```

I type in `javac MiniMusicPlayer1.java` and it gives me a number of errors, all related to midievent. The first error says Midievent.java:1 error: class...expected.

The main error I see is

> "cannot access Midievent...bad source file .\MidiEvent.java.....file does not contain class MidiEvent....Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath

What could the problem be? I read other people using the same code without issues

Comment: This might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117680/java-package-does-not-exist-and-bad-source-file

Comment: omg I found out my own answer..sorry everyone...It turns out I actually had another class named MidiEvent in the folder ><!!!!thanks for that link though I still learned something helpful lol.

Comment: If you want to be hardcore and do everything from the command line, that's an extremely useful link.  I'd use an IDE though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have the class MidiEvent defined elsewhere, then this code will not compile, as it requires the MidiEvent class.

Based on the error message, it looks like you have a `MidiEvent.java` file, however the java compiler is not able to find the class `MidiEvent` in it, either because the file is malformed, or the file is incorrectly named.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the capitalization of the name other source file (`MidiEvent.java`) and the capitalization of the name of the class inside it (`Midievent`, seemingly) are the same.