# compile a java class with package name in another java class file by using javac

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to compile a java class file in another java class file by using javac command. It went well if these two file do not have any package name with them.

Class Laj

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Laj {

      private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
        }
      }

      private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        pro.waitFor();
        if(pro.exitValue() != 0){
            System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());    
        }       
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          runProcess("javac simpleTest.java");
          runProcess("java simpleTest");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Class  SimpleTest

```
public class simpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What's wrong with it");
    }
}
```

I can use the commands *javac Laj.java* and *java Laj* to compile and run them well. However if I add the package name, for example *package compileTest* in the front of these two classes and modify the runProcess part of the code in Laj to

```
runProcess("javac -d . compileTest.simpleTest.java");
runProcess("java compileTest.simpleTest");
```

the code would not work.

Can anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected it to; packages are folder structures, and your files aren't in a folder structure.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12117680/1079354), while not *exactly* a duplicate, can get you past the initial pain.

Comment: I think you need to specify the classpath. ie. use "-cp ." If that does not work, play around with the -cp argument.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do not you use 'JavaCompiler' class to compile your java file. Please see below example I have compiled a java class with package name.

```
Package Name = com.main
Class Name = MainClass.java
Source Dir = src

public  void compileClass() {
        System.setProperty("java.home", "G:\\Java\\Tools\\installed\\JDK");   // Set JDK path it will help to get compiler
        File root = new File("/src");   // Source Directory 
        File sourceFile = new File(root, "com/main/MainClass.java");    // Java file name with package 
        sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try {
            new FileWriter(sourceFile).close();  // Read Java file
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        System.out.println(compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath()));
    }
```

Comment: ...Why would you feel the need to do this?

Comment: It is an alternative as I also written in first line of answer. It is also doing the same thing compiling a java source file.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with `JavaCompiler`.  However, that's not what the question is asking, nor is it really helpful for this particular issue.

Comment: SO you are trying this as second approach to compile the java file. I thought you stuck in compiling java file so suggested that alternative solution. I am sorry for that :)